# Is there any easy way to get "value" of a cookie and save it in a .txt file using python?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, session-cookies

I am trying to get cookies from a website to automate certain requests. Currently, I'm using selenium's *get_cookie* function to get the cookie.

```
driver.get_cookie("cookie-name-here")
```

This returns a **dict** in the following format:

```
{'domain': 'website-name-here', 'expiry': 29630, 'name': 'cookie-name', 'path': '/', 'value':'the-string-that-I-need'}
```

**I only need the data under the 'value' attribute.**
If there is any easier way to get value in JS, I'm open to that as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have a dict like this :

```
cookies = {'domain': 'website-name-here', 'expiry': 29630, 'name': 'cookie-name', 'path': '/', 'value':'the-string-that-I-need'}
```

the easiest way would be to get the value is to use `.get`

```
val = cookies.get('value')
print(val)
```

or in other words, the below code also should return the **value**.

```
print(driver.get_cookie("cookie-name-here").get('value'))
```